# Remove a div after is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, setcookie

I want to remove the parent of a div after it is clicked and store a cookie "clicked" with value true. I use JavaScript Cookie to store cookie. So I have a blog with adsense and I want to hide my ads to protect from invalid activity after user click on it 1 time.

This is my code:

```
  $("#firstCode").click(function () {
       $(this).parent().hide();

       var date = new Date();
       var h = "1";
       date.setTime(date.getTime() + (h * 60 * 60 * 1000));

       Cookies.set('clicked', 'true', {expires: date, path: '/'});
  });
```

and html code:

```
<div id="codeWrapper">
   <div id="firstCode">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7094677798399606";
         google_ad_slot = "8373705259";
         google_ad_width = 728;
         google_ad_height = 90;
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
      </script>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work. If someone can find where is my problem, I very appreciate it.

Comment: can you post html?

Comment: Which line throws error? you can check it from your developer console. And btw, if you're using jQuery, you can set cookie by `$.cookie('clicked', 'true')`.

Comment: when u say **but it doesn't work**, you mean the div hiding or the cookes storage ?

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't something anyone can help you with. *What* doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you define a string variable and then use it in a calculation?  What is that string?  Should it be a number instead?

Comment: hiding div and storing cookie doesnt work too

Comment: have you include required jquery?

Comment: @JürgenKruja: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3pqjb24x/  How exactly is this failing for you?  You have to describe the problem, nobody here can see your screen.

Comment: "It doesn't work" ... does it lay on the couch all day watching TV ? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove an element from DOM

```
$("#firstCode").click(function () {
  var date = new Date();
  var h = "<?php echo html_entity_decode(get_option('fs_time_cookie')); ?>";
       date.setTime(date.getTime() + (h * 60 * 60 * 1000));
       Cookies.set('clicked', 'true', {expires: date, path: '/'});
   $(this).parent().remove();
  });
```